# div style inline nowrap for HTML email signature

Tags: html, styles, nowrap

I am creating an HTML email signature and on small devices such as a phone, I can not keep it from wrapping when the screen resolution is not wide enough for the signature.  I have tried a combination of everything I found here, either one or more of several suggestions on similar issues, but nothing seems to be working.

Here is the correct sig and two versions that are incorrect:

[signature examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qBkh.png)

Here is the code we currently have:

```
<div style="line-height:18px; margin:0px; padding: 0px 8px 8px 0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#1e394e; display:inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; min-width:500px;">
```

Sonnie  Parker
*Partner,  Senior Administrator*
334-482-4248   avnirvana.com

Comment: It is not showing all of the code... not sure how to get it to show up.

Comment: <div style="line-height:18px; margin:0px; padding: 0px 8px 8px 0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#1e394e; display:inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; min-width:500px;"><a href="https://www.avnirvana.com"><img src="https://www.avnirvana.com/images/email_logo.png" style="float:left;  padding:0px 7px 0px 0px; border-right:2px solid #000000;"></a><strong style="color:#1e394e; font-size:16px; padding:0px 0px 0px 7px; display:inline-block;">Sonnie  Parker</strong><br>

Comment: <span style="color:#1e394e; font-size:14px; padding:0px 0px 0px 7px; display:inline-block;"><em>Partner,  Senior Administrator</em></span><br>
<span style="color:#1e394e; font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; padding:0px 0px 0px 7px;">334-482-4248</span>   <a href="https://www.avnirvana.com" style="color:#0f67b5 !important;">avnirvana.com</a><br>

Comment: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/avnirvana/" style="color:#1e394e; padding:0px 0px 0px 7px;"><img src="http://www.avnirvana.com/images/facebook_icon.gif" style="padding:2px 0px 0px 0;" border="0"></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/AV_NIRVANA" style="color:#1e394e;"><img  src="http://www.avnirvana.com/images/twitter_icon.gif" style="padding:2px 0px 0px 0;" border="0"></a>
</div>

Comment: Please put your code in your original post in a code sample or snippet.

Comment: Sorry... it would not allow me to insert all of the code, but I worked it out with tables and it works just fine now.  I would post it but don't know how and don't see instructions on how to do it anywhere.  Site is just not very functional for newbies or those trying to learn.  No offense to anyone... it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The signature will always wrap because the image container is set to float. This is good if you want your code to be responsive and display differently on smaller devices. If you want the two halves to always be side by side, I would specify their widths relative to their parent. Also, I'd recommend organizing your code with `div` tags.

```css
.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.parent>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 7px;
  border-right: 2px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left img {
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  color: #1e394e;
  padding-left: 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <a href="avnirvana.com">
      <img src="https://www.avnirvana.com/images/email_logo.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div>
      <strong>Sonnie Parker</strong>
    </div>
    <div>
      <em>Partner, Senior Administrator</em>
    </div>
    <div>
      334-482-4248 <a href="avnirvana.com" ; style="color:#0f67b5 !important;">avnirvana.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```